# How do I upload image in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Please, below is my code in the script section of my vue component.

I'm getting all the input fields right but the image and video uploads are showing empty values.

I have tried to solve this issue but to no avail.

```
        playVideo(url) {
            let video = $('#video-preview').get(0);
            video.preload = 'metadata';
            // Load video in Safari / IE11
            if (url) {
                video.muted = false;
                video.playsInline = true;
                video.play();
            }
        },

        // Read a file input as a data URL.
        readDataUrl(input, callback) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function () {
                    callback(fileReader.result);
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                callback(null);
            }
        },

        // Read a file input as an object url.
        readObjectUrl(input, callback) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function () {
                    let blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: input.files[0].type});
                    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    callback(url, blob);
                };
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                callback(null);
            }

        },

    }

}
```

What exactly I want to achieve is upload image and video file, preview them before saving as blob.

[image: the response]

The above image shows my response @samayo

The image and video blob are showing empty values.

Comment: To which URL are you trying to upload? Is it put/post request?

Comment: I'm using: submit() {
                let data = new FormData;
                data.append('description', this.description);
                data.append('displays', this.boards);
                data.append('messages', JSON.stringify(this.messages));

                /*for(let property in this.messages) {
                    data.append('messages', JSON.stringify(this.messages[property]));
                }*/

                axios.post('/campaign', data).then(response => {
                    this.feedback = response.data;
                }).catch(response.data);
            }

Answer (score 27):

I think in your case you are looking for a solution like this

example: **uploading a image and previewing it before submission**

```
<template>
   <div>
      <img src:"previewImage" class="uploading-image" />
      <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" @change=uploadImage>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'imageUpload',
        data(){
            return{
               previewImage:null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            uploadImage(e){
                const image = e.target.files[0];
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                reader.onload = e =>{
                    this.previewImage = e.target.result;
                    console.log(this.previewImage);
                };
            }
        }
     }  // missing closure added
</script>



<style>
   .uploading-image{
     display:flex;
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: Note that this code doesn't UPLOAD anything anywhere, it just reads the file from drive and displays it in the browser.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using `axios` or `fetch` uploading files with vue is pretty easy.

This is a copy/pasta from my current project. I use axios to upload images:

First you'll need to have your input look like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="uploadImage($event)" id="file-input">
```

Then add a method like this:

```
methods: {

  uploadImage(event) {

    const URL = 'http://foobar.com/upload'; 

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('name', 'my-picture');
    data.append('file', event.target.files[0]); 

    let config = {
      header : {
        'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
      }
    }

    axios.put(
      URL, 
      data,
      config
    ).then(
      response => {
        console.log('image upload response > ', response)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I upload video file, preview it and save it as blob. That is what I'm trying to achieve. @samayo Same thing applies to the image file.

Comment: I know how you can capture an image by accessing user's camera and upload it, b/c I am working on a library that does that but I don't know how to record a video but it should be easy according to the specifications of `mediaDevices` I'll share maybe if I implement the feature here

Comment: @samayo how can I display it the image after I've choose it

Comment: @Choy I forgot, I worked on vue very briefly but I remember it was very easy, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/97dzkf70 you can get the idea

Comment: @samayo btw may I know whats the ` const URL = 'http://foobar.com/upload'; ` refer to? 
If I'm using localhost should I change to localhost url?

Comment: Yes, change `http://foobar.com/upload` to `localhost/foobar` or `localhost/foobar.php` but the PHP file must accept post data, you can also use js instead of php

Comment: for me changing header to 
`headers: { Accept: 'application/json',  'Content-Type': 'application/json', }`
 worked

Answer (score 12):

**If you want to upload an image and preview it before submission** you can use simple and functional way as optionally.

```
<template>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onChange" />
  <div id="preview">
    <img v-if="item.imageUrl" :src="item.imageUrl" />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'imageUpload',
  data() {
    return {
      item:{
          //...
          image : null,
          imageUrl: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0]
      this.image = file
      this.item.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm taking from a few other peoples answers to sum it up.

`this.image` is base64 encoded and ready to send to your API.

```
<template>
    <v-file-input
       v-model="file"
       chips
       accept="image/*"
       label="Image"
       @change="onFileChange"
    />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: { file: null, image: null },
    methods: {
        onFileChange() {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.file)
            reader.onload = e => {
                this.image = e.target.result
                console.log(this.image)
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything together and you will have both a preview and perform the upload, don't forget to replace the URL with your destination on the server.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <img src:"previewImage" class="uploading-image" />
        <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" @change=uploadImage>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'imageUpload', 
        data(){
            return{
                previewImage:null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            uploadImage(e){
                const image = e.target.files[0];
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                reader.onload = e =>{
                    this.previewImage = e.target.result;
                    console.log(this.previewImage);
                };

                const URL = 'http://foobar.com/upload'; 

                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('name', 'my-picture');
                data.append('file', e.target.files[0]); 

                let config = {
                    header : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
                    }
                }

                axios.put(URL,data,config).then(response => {
                    console.log('image upload response > ', response)
                })
            }

        }
    } 
</script>

<style>
    .uploading-image{display:flex;}
</style>
```