# Image doesnt save (Laravel & Vue Js)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Template

```html
<form @submit.prevent=" addUser()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="addUser">Password</label>
      <input type="tex" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name"    name="name" v-model="form.name"
         :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }">
      <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="tex" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" v-model="form.email"
         :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }">
      <has-error :form="form" field="email"></has-error>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="picture">Picture</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" placeholder="Picture" name="image" >                   
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

JavaScript

```js
import Form from 'vform'

export default {
  name: "Users",
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        name: '',
        email: '',

      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addUser() {
      this.form.post('/addUser').
      then((response) => {
        console.log('I clicked');
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Laravel

```php
$this->validate($request,[
   'name'=> 'required',
   'email'=> 'required '
]);

$newUser = New NewUser();
$newUser->name = $request->name;
$newUser->email = $request->email;*/

if($request->hasFile('image')){
   $imageN = $request->image;
   $request->image->storeAs('public/upload',$imageN);
}
$newUser->save();
```

Comment: Did you *look* at this before posting it?

Comment: what is the error you face?

Comment: No error is showing but file dont save

Answer (score 0):

The image file is not being save because it is never being send with the request to laravel.
You could either add the image to the `new Form()` or check out the following post on how to upload an image: [How do I upload image in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650154/how-do-i-upload-image-in-vuejs/58231597)

Comment: Then how can i send a request to my laravel controller.

Comment: The link i provided show how you can unload an image. It does this by creating a request body where it appends the image to the data. What you have to do is the same for laravel. You are creating a user object and sending that. What you could do is create an request object that contains the user object as well as the image or add the image to the user object